# changing css background from sql database of particular div

Tags: mysql, css, asp.net, vb.net, dynamic-css

I have a div where it's property set runat="server" with its ID. I'm trying to put dynamic background image for that particular div from MySQL database where it's path url mentioned in row. Now all working fine but I don't know how to give style affect to that particular div only. Currently I defined only on div which results to get background image in all div on that page. How can I define that div class or ID in my code?

```
Private Sub coverContent_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles coverContent.Init
        Try
            Dim css As New HtmlGenericControl()
            css.TagName = "style"
            css.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css")
            Dim imageURL As String = String.Empty
            Dim var3 As String
            var3 = Request.QueryString("hospitalID")

            Dim str As String = "Select hospitalID, coverImage from hospitals where hospitalID='" + var3 + "';"
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(str, con)
            Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            con.Close()
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                generalID.Text = dt.Rows(0)("hospitalID").ToString
                imageURL = dt.Rows(0)("coverImage").ToString
            End If
            con.Close()
            css.InnerHtml = (Convert.ToString("div{background-image: url(") & imageURL) + ");}"

            Page.Header.Controls.Add(css)

            MyBase.OnInit(e)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming you also create HTML dynamically, posting your code for that as well, would make it easier for us to suggest the best way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple where you have mentioned div there you need to specify class of div where you want to show background image. Like below

```
css.InnerHtml = (Convert.ToString(".divClassName{background-image: url(") & imageURL) + ");}"
```